# Xcode 8.2.1 iOS simulator slow

Tags: performance, ios-simulator, xcode8, macos-sierra

I bought a new mac book pro.

System features:

> 2.0GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 processor, Turbo Boost up to 3.1GHz
>
> 8GB 1866MHz memory
>
> 256GB PCIe-based SSD
>
> Intel Iris Graphics 540
>
> Two Thunderbolt 3 ports
>
> MacOs Sierra 10.12.1

You can see the details from [here](http://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/macbook-pro?product=MLL42LL/A&step=config#)

My problem is, I installed xcode 8.2.1 and tested it. It's really fast, but there's slowdown in the simulator. Deceleration is not in page transitions, but in scrolling actions.I've tried both the iOS 9.0 and the iOS 10.2 simulator, but the situation is the same.

I have found a solution that I have researched. "Close the debug-slow animations option in the simulator" but this is not the case.

I do not know if the issue is related to xcode or sierra, but I do not think it's about hardware. I tried it for Android emulator, but it worked very fast. I do not know if there is a connection, but I think that if the hardware is inadequate, it should work slowly in the android emulator.

**Do you have an idea on this?**

Comment: Did you try resetting the simulator? Did you have an eye on the CPU usage (Activity Monitor) when the sim seems to be slow? Can you confirm that the simulator is much faster when started from Xcode 7.3.1 on the same machine?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried "Reset Content and Settings" but I did not get any results. I installed Xcode 7.3.1 and run the simulator, but the result was the same. Is there a problem with MacOS sierra?